# Maximum contiguous sum in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge, array

The following code is my solution for the following Daily Coding Challenge

> Given an array of numbers, find the maximum sum of any contiguous
>   subarray of the array.
>
> For example, given the array [34, -50, 42, 14, -5, 86], the maximum
>   sum would be 137, since we would take elements 42, 14, -5, and 86.
>
> Given the array [-5, -1, -8, -9], the maximum sum would be 0, since we
>   would not take any elements.
>
> Do this in O(N) time.

I think this is done in `O(N)` time and is the best solution. If someone can think of a better way, I would be interested.

```
array = [4, -2, 7, -9]
running_sum = 0
for i in range(1,len(array)):
    if array[i-1] > 0:
        array[i] = array[i] + array[i-1]
    else: 
        array[i-1] = 0
print(max(array))
```

Comment: You can remove `running_sum = 0` :)

Comment: Although it is not specified in the problem statement, the space complexity is also important. Your algorithm exhibits an \$O(n)\$ time complexity (because it mutates an array). There exists a constant space, linear time solution.

Comment: Surely you have to store the array to process it. Therefore my not making a new variable, the space complexity is the same? @vnp

Comment: The space complexity does not account for the space taken by the input.

Comment: I am curious how this would work. Because saying something like ```max_value = maximum(max_value, max_value + array[i])``` wouldn't work. How can you predict the ```i+1``` or ```i+2``` value in linear time complexity. Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## changing mutable object

Since you are changing the original array, this code run twice can provide strange results. In general I try to avoid changing the arguments passed into a function I write, unless it's explicitly stated, or expected (like `list.sort`)

## `accumulate`

What you are looking for is the largest difference between tha cumulative sum where the minimum comes before the maximum. Calculating the cumulative sum can be done with `itertools.accumulate`. Then you just have to keep track of the minimum of this running sum and the difference with the running minimum

```
def best_sum_accum(array):
    running_min = 0
    max_difference = 0
    for cumsum in accumulate(array):
        if cumsum > running_min:
            max_difference = max(max_difference,  cumsum - running_min)
        running_min = min(running_min, cumsum)
    return max_difference
```

Comment: Surely this has a time complexity > ```O(N)``` because you have a nested loop? ```for``` and ```max```?

Comment: Not really, you loop 1 timer through the array. On each iteration, you compare 2 numbers, so the time complexity is linear with the length of the array. Space complexity is constant

Answer (score 1):

I would merge the 2 loops (there is one in the max part), since not all parts are relevant for the maximum:

```
def best_subsum(array):
    running_sum = 0
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        if array[i-1] > 0:
            array[i] = array[i] + array[i-1]
            if array[i] > running_sum: running_sum = array[i]
    return running_sum

array = [4, -2, 7, -9]
print(best_subsum(array))
```

Note that branch prediction shouldnt be too much of a problem, since running sum is not check until the same if statement in the next succeding iteration.